# Pyplot: Refreshing an imshow() Window

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I've got two methods: generate_window() which shows an image and on_click() which reacts to a click on the window showing the image. They look like this:

```
def generate_panel(img):
  plt.figure()
  ax = plt.gca()
  fig = plt.gcf()
  implot = ax.imshow(img)
  # When a colour is clicked on the image an event occurs
  cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
  plt.show()

def onclick(event):
  if event.xdata != None and event.ydata != None:
    # Change the contents of the plt window here
```

On the last line of the code I want to be able to change the image shown in the plt window but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried set_data() and draw() in different places but that hasn't worked. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have also to enable interactive mode using `plt.ion()`
then just calling `plt.draw()` after the your modification should work.

NB: When using interactive mode you have to specify the argument `block=True` on `plt.show()` in order to prevent it from immediately closing the window.

This modified version of your example should plot a circle on every mouse click:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np


def generate_panel(img):
    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.gca()
    fig = plt.gcf()
    implot = ax.imshow(img)
    # When a colour is clicked on the image an event occurs
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
    plt.show(block=True)


def onclick(event):
    if event.xdata is not None and event.ydata is not None:
        circle = plt.Circle((event.xdata,
                             event.ydata), 2, color='r')
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.gca().add_artist(circle)
        plt.draw()
        # Change the contents of the plt window here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plt.ion()
    img = np.ones((600, 800, 3))
    generate_panel(img)
```

Comment: How would you implement this for matplotlib subplots i.e. you want to update a specific subplot when a certain method is called?

Comment: I'm not totally sure of this, maybe it depends on the backend you are using.
I believe that matplotlib is rendering the whole canvas every time you call `draw()` function. 
You can put different axes/plot in different figures/cavases and update them selectively with `fig_n.canvas.draw()`.
Another way is to put all subplot in the same canvas/figure and update their data selectively but rendering always the whole canvas (all subplots).